# Convert number to date time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hi i have this query converting number to date time

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + (('1602400733') / (60 * 60 * 24)), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') from dual
```

which give me result of `10/11/2020 07:18:53 AM`

how can make this time to number again in reverse?

sorry im new at oracle i dont know how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how to convert a date to an epoch timestamp.

Here is a simple approach, that is consistent with your current code that turns the epoch to a date:

```
(mydate - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24
```

`mydate` represents the `date` value that you want to convert.

Note that this uses the standard `date 'YYYY-MM-DD'` to declare date literals, rather than using `to_date()`. Using this syntax, your original code would be simpler expressed as:

```
date '1970-01-01' + mynumber / 60 / 60 / 24
```